# Compare files, then enter coordinates into perl script then run perl script with pre-written commands and coordinates

Tags: perl, batch-file, perl-module, mod-perl

I would like a batch that reads a file called ships.txt, then takes the entries (each on a line) from that file and compares them to a file with the file extension of *.map (say test.map), looking for the match, which will always be at the end of a line. Then take those coordinates (they will be a pair of numbers that are actually long. and lat. in meters) and plug those coordinates into a perl script, which produces a file. I'd like then to read the file that is produced by the perl script and delete an entry that is found within another file using information from the perl script by-product.

Lets start from scratch. One step at a time
Step 1:

1. I would like a batch that compares "test.map" and "ships.txt". If it finds a match, and the match will always be at the end of a line in test.map, I'd like it to grab map coordinates.

This is what test.map will look like:

Code:

```
 Pt0=14497903.00,-813490.00,0.00,Mark 1
 Pt1=14417253.00,-812258.00,0.00,Mark 2
 etc...
```

ships.txt will look something like this:

```
 Mark 1
 Mark 3
 etc...
```

So I'd like the batch to read ships.txt and be looking for the entry "Mark 1" or "Mark 2" etc..., and if it is found in test.map, to grab the coordinates just before the ",0.00,Mark #" Notice the coordinates have two decimal places and they can also be negative.

How is this done?

Comment: You forgot to add a question to your question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a "write this program for me" service.

Comment: You'd like a script, I'd like some money. Perhaps we should trade? I've actually already done this part already.

Comment: Perhaps we should not.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it could be done.

Here is how you could [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) a file for read or write in perl. Then you have to [read](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/readwritefiles.htm) the files, line by line. Maybe it is better to use [text::csv](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) to read the files.

Use split or text::csv to create array from the first file lines, and store it in a hash, key should the last field of that file.

When you iterate over the second file, you could use this hash to check it in the first file or not.

Then write your result to a file.

Try to write your code and if you have a specific question you could create a new one.

Or you could hire someone to do this for you.

Regards